# StackExchange Theme Switcher

Tags: script, style

Inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/116522/eeeeek-what-the-fruit-is-going-on-with-all-these-theme-changes). Now you too can enjoy the satisfaction of switching SE's themes at will like the devs do, albeit this affects your browser only:

[image]

This creates a dropdown at the bottom of the page that allows you to switch themes:

[image: desc]

### Installation

Click [HERE](https://gist.github.com/raw/1499727/se_themer.user.js) to install the user script.

Click [HERE](https://gist.github.com/1499727) to preview the code.

Comment: In order for the "click HERE" link to actually install the script, it needs to have the extension '.user.js' instead of just '.js'.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Is there a way to apply the changes *before* the page loads?

Comment: Unfortunately no, a UserScript is only run once the page loads.